# set cli complete-on-space Cisco equivalent

Tags: cisco, juniper, juniper-junos, cisco-commands

Does anyone know what would be the equivalent, if any, of the Juniper command `set cli complete-on-space` for Cisco?  I used to work with Juniper devices and I LOVED this feature, but now we are strictly a Cisco shop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Cisco command completion uses the `<TAB>` key (one of the Juniper options).

Cisco commands also do not even need to be complete to work; they only need to be complete enough to be unambiguous. For example, most people type `sh run` rather than the full `show running-config`.

You can also type `?` to get the list of options.